# flutter could not resolve gradle configurations

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

after update my android studio plugins and some tools(mar 2021) i tried to run my flutter app in android studio (4.1.2) but it give me that err ...

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':path_provider:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.3.0/builder-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/3.3.0/gradle-api-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.3.0/sdk-common-26.3.0.jar
   > Could not find bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.6.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.6.0/bundletool-0.6.0.jar
   > Could not find protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.3.0/protos-26.3.0.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/3.3.0/databinding-common-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.3.0/baseLibrary-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin path_provider...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'path_provider'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.3.0/builder-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/3.3.0/gradle-api-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find sdk-common.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/26.3.0/sdk-common-26.3.0.jar
   > Could not find bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.6.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.6.0/bundletool-0.6.0.jar
   > Could not find protos.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.3.0/protos-26.3.0.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/3.3.0/databinding-common-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.3.0/baseLibrary-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 994ms

Exception: The plugin path_provider could not be built due to the issue above.
```

but i didnt add **path_provider** to **pubspec.yaml** but it give that exception to me about that plugin course some packages i add may use that.
i runned pub upgrade and pub get and other ways like take path_privider.x_x_x folders from .pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\ folder but it didnt work.

Comment: first try `flutter clean` then  open `android` folder in android studio to get all `required` dependencies then run app

Comment: @GJJ2019 did that before and didnt work

Comment: fixed in android studio 4.1.3 update